# file_get_contents load error and loop?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I just looking for solution to load content using `file_get_contents`
My script works fine, but sometimes file are not load, i know how to check if `file_get_contents` fails but how to try get it again without page reload?

```
$url = file_get_contents('url.to.file');
if ( $url === false )
{
    // code to do it again, how?  
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep trying to load the file if the first attempt fails?

Comment: yes, just looking for this

Comment: Are you sure it will work eventually? What happens if it never gets the file

Comment: Yes, it will be work. Sometimes i need to reload page 4 times and file are loading fine, so will be good to try get content again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you could try runnning the get in a loop

```
$max_loop = 5;

while (FALSE == $url = file_get_contents('url.to.file') ) {
    $cur_loop++
    if ( $cur_loop >= $max_loop )
        // indicate an error so can be put on page
        break;
    }
}
```

Written in a function it might look like this

```
function get_url($the_url, $max_try)
    $cur_loop = 0;

    while (FALSE == $url = file_get_contents($the_url) ) {
        $cur_loop++
        if ( $cur_loop >= $max_try )
            break;
        }
    }

    return $url;
}

//called like this
$data = get_url('the.url',5);
if ( $data === false ) {
    // error message
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution:)

Comment: It's possible to write it using function for any url?

Comment: There you go, written as a function.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome snippet! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found my own solution with for loop. 
it will try 5 times to load file if will load for loop will be break

```
                $url = file_get_contents('File');
                if ( $url === false ) {
                    for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {
                        $url = file_get_contents('File');
                        if ( $url === true ) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                }
```

Comment: The function file_get_contents returns the read data or FALSE on failure. Cheking with true won't work. So instead of using if ( $url === true ) 
use if ( $url !== false ).